# Mastermind recreation if statements stuck

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm recreating the Mastermind game and I'm stuck on some "if" statements
i am trying make it tell the user that if the color is not the same as in `guess1`but is the proper color is `guess2` it will `print "guess 1 right color wrong position"`

Python V- 2.7.8

```
colors =  ('R','B','G','P','Y','O')
Color1 = random.choice(colors)
Color2 = random.choice(colors)
Color3 = random.choice(colors)
Color4 = random.choice(colors)
guess1 = raw_input("First Color: ") 
guess2 = raw_input("Second Color: ")
guess3 = raw_input("Third Color: ")
guess4 = raw_input("Fourth Color: ")
guesses = (guess1,guess2,guess3,guess4)
Allcolors = (Color1,Color2,Color3,Color4)

if guesses == Allcolors:
        print "All colors are correct!"
    if guesses != Allcolors:
####
        if guess1 == Color2 or Color3 or Color4:
            print "Guess 1 right color wrong position"
        if guess1 == Color1:
            print "Color 1 is correct"
####
        if guess2 == Color2:
            print "Color 2 is correct"
        if guess3 == Color3:
            print "Color 3 is correct"
        if guess4 == Color4:
            print "Color 4 is correct"
```

Comment: Is the indentation here identical to the indentation of your local code?  If so, see how you'll never have both `guesses == Allcolors` and `guesses != Allcolors`

Answer (score 0):

```
if guess1 == Color2 or Color3 or Color4:
```

This doesn't work. You have to repeat the variable:

```
if guess1 == Color2 or guess1 == Color3 or guess1 == Color4:
```

You can also use `in` operator to look in a container:

```
if guess1 in (Color2, Color3, Color4):
```